MessagePack и Generic-типы
Перехожу на использование msgpack вместо JSON и столкнулся с проблемой.
В общем, от внешнего сервера я получаю коллекцию объектов типа:
class B {
 public string Type;
 public object Value;
}

Когда был JSON, то value представляло JObject и можно сделать просто jObj.ToObject<T>(), то при использовании msgpack  value представляет собой Dictionary<object, object>, который я так просто не знаю, как привести к нужному типу.
Отсюда вопросы:

Нет ли в msgpack какой-нибудь отложенной десериализации? Когда я могу позже десериализовать в нужный тип?
Если первого нет, то нет ли какой-то либы, которая автоматически замапит этот словарь на нужный тип?


А какую библиотеку ты используешь? Там 2 реализации, и то что тебе необходимо есть в MPack https://github.com/caesay/MPack. https://github.com/caesay/MPack/blob/master/MPack%2FMToken.cs#L360
